# ASP.NET MVC 2 Model object validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I'm trying to validate a model object outside of the context of ModelState within a controller, I currently have a parser that creates model objects from an excel file and I want to be able to report how many entries were added to the database and how many failed, is there a way to validate a model object on its data annotations outside of model binding?

I'm looking for something similar to the rails model method of `model.valid?` or a way for me to implement that myself.

My current solution is just manually checking if a few key fields are present but this duplicates requirements between my model class and its metadata, there has to be a better way to hook into the model validation checking that is done by mvc 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Validator` class which can be found as part of `DataAnnotations`.

```
User userEntity = new User();

var validationContext = new ValidationContext(userEntity, null, null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(userEntity, validationContext, validationResults, true);
```

In case all your entities or application/domain model classes inherit from the same class, you can put this code in parent class or as an extension method to keep your class clean.

Otherwise you're going to use singleton pattern to create a special static validator. You can use validation results to your liking.

### Metadata classes

If you're using metadata classes to define validation rules for your entities, you should register metadata classes prior to validation:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
    new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
        typeof(User),
        typeof(UserMetadata)
    ),
    typeof(User)
);

Validator.TryValidateObject(userEntity, context, results, true);
```

Comment: This looks promising but does it read validation rules from my entity's metadata class? My simple tests using it have ignored things like regular expression validations on fields

Comment: I guess you're gonna've to test it. Since it's data annotations native validator I suppose it obeys metadata class validation definitions. But you should test it. What about other rules? Are regular expression rules the only ones that don't work?

Comment: Yeah I had tried it, which is why I commented, didn't know if it was designed to read from metadata when validating or if I had done something wrong, the errors I'm getting are that no errors are thrown for missing required fields or fields that don't pass regular expression validation., even with your updated answer